# How to convert miles into km and vice versa?

Tags: ruby

I cannot figure out how to create this conversion, something about math no matter how minute it is rattles my brain.

My class

```
class Distance

def convert(miles_to_km, km_to_miles)
    miles_to_km = 1 * 1.60934
    km_to_miles = 1 * 0.621371

end

end
```

or should it be something like
    class Distance

```
def convert(value, unit)
     some data i have yet to understand
end
end
```

my added input

```
puts "______________Adding: _____________"

d1 = Distance.new(1, "m")
d2 = Distance.new(1, "k")

puts d1 + d2

d1 = Distance.new(2, "M")
d2 = Distance.new(2, "m")

d3 = d1 + d2
puts d3
puts d3.value
puts d3.unit

d1 = Distance.new(3, "k")
d2 = Distance.new(3, "K")

puts d1 + d2

d1 = Distance.new(4, "k")
d2 = Distance.new(4, "m")

puts d1 + d2

puts "-" * 30 ############
```

Results should be

```
______________Adding _____________
1.621371 Miles
4 Miles
4
m
6 Kilometers
10.43736 Kilometers
```

Answer (score 3):

Your methods need to be specific to your actions.

```
def convert(miles_to_km, km_to_miles)
  miles_to_km = 1 * 1.60934
  km_to_miles = 1 * 0.621371
end
```

Should be

```
def convert_miles_to_km(km)
  return km * 1.60934
end
```

and vice versa

Comment: It would be more appropriate to name the input miles. `def convert_miles_to_km(miles)`

Answer (score 1):

### Parse String Arguments for Flexibility

There are lots of ways to solve this problem. A lot depends one what sort of input you expect from the caller, and what sort of result you want to pass back as your return values.

Sometimes it's useful to be less rigorous about how one *expresses* units of measurement while still being strict about the way the conversions are performed. Here is an example where a single method takes a string as input, and returns an appropriate floating-point value for predefined units such as kilometers or miles while remaining flexible about the *way* the distance units are expressed.

```
# Use constants for your conversion ratios.
MI_TO_KM = 1.60934
KM_TO_MI = 0.621371

# Make your method more flexible by accepting a string
# containing both a distance and a unit identifier.
def convert_distance str
    dist, unit = str.scan(/([\d.]+)\s*(\S+)/).flatten
    case unit
    when /^k/i
      dist.to_f * KM_TO_MI
    when /^m/i
      dist.to_f * MI_TO_KM
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "unknown unit: #{unit.inspect}"
    end
end
```

This will provide you with the following sample outputs:

```
convert_distance '10 miles'
#=> 16.0934

convert_distance '10 kilometers'
#=> 6.21371

convert_distance '3mi'
#=> 4.82802

convert_distance '3km'
#=> 1.8641130000000001

convert_distance '1 cubit'
#=> ArgumentError: unknown unit: "cubit"
```

This type of method isn't necessarily the simplest way to get the job done, but it certainly prevents you from having to define different methods for "km", "kilometers", "klicks", and so forth. It's also easily expandable for other units of distance (e.g. "yards") simply by adding a new clause with the appropriate conversion ratio to the case statement.